# VUEJS Compile problem 76% basic chunk optimization RemoveParentModulesPlugin

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vue-component, npm-run

I use vuejs in my project. After developing some days i face a big problem in compilation. When i compile my project using `npm run serve my` its takes 2-3 minutes in `76% basic chunk optimization RemoveParentModulesPlugin` .
My node version: 11.12
npm version: 6.7

This is my vue.config.js

```
var path = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/mss';

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  baseUrl:path,
  // baseUrl:'http://192.168.1.43:8080'
}
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: Is your project using `vue-cli`? I have found the cli to cause many issues. You may need to reconfigure the project with plain old webpack (try 4)

Comment: so may i reconfigure package.json ??? @Michael

Comment: I am not sure of the details, you may either want to migrate (google this how it is done), or just make an entirely new project and copy in your components and starts with a clean webpack with default config

Comment: already do .. but its not works ... @Michael

Comment: can you please share your webpack configs?

Comment: i edit my question here i use vue.config.js ...

Comment: Seems like you are not actually configuring webpack rather Vue is doing that for you. Do you not have a file webpack.config or webpack something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194156/discussion-between-nadimul-de-cj-and-michael).